# Remote Pagination with Tabulator and asp.net web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, tabulator

I'm using this http://tabulator.info/docs/4.8/page#remote plugin for my gridviews. It is amazing but I'm struggling in one area. I need to perform remote pagination. I don't know what to put in these two parameters

```
ajaxURL:"http://testdata.com/data", //set url for ajax request
    ajaxParams:{token:"ABC123"},
```

When I am using asp.net Allowpaging method, my gridview doesn't create footer. Please help me how to solve this.

Comment: First I would read the entire link you posted. It goes into detail what information is needed and what should be returned.  With remote pagination the server takes care of breaking the data down into pages. The URLs and supplied parameters are those that need to reach the server and provide the information needed to do the previous. Second I don't know about Allowpaging, so I will not be of help there. Have you tried without it?

Comment: Allowpaging is a Asp.net function, I tried with and without it. Do you got any idea about the url I need to write there?